# WPF one row in datagrind change another row

Tags: wpf

This is my grid, which contains all cinema seances:

```
<Grid>
  <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dgSeance">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data" Binding="{Binding date}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Czas" Binding="{Binding time}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Czas trwania" Binding="{Binding duration}"/>

            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Film" x:Name="movieComboBox" ItemsSource="{StaticResource movieList}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Movie.title}"/>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

In cs file I set datacontext:

```
    CinemaEntities _context = new CinemaEntities;
    dgSeance.ItemsSource = _context.Seance;
```

And when I change movie title in one seance from A to B, all seances which have movie A get now movie B. Any solution for this behaviour?

Comment: Can you also show the class definition of Seance?

Answer (score 0):

ok I solved my problem

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Film" x:Name="movieComboBox" ItemsSource="{StaticResource movieList}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=movieId}" SelectedValuePath="id" DisplayMemberPath="title"/>
```